# Merge Replication - Deleting from the subscriber database?

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication

I have 2 SQL Server instances where I use merge replication on a database. A developer accidentally inserted data to both the subscriber and publisher at the same time.  Now I have data in both databases but with different rowguids.

Q: Can I delete those rows with different rowguids from the subscriber and the rows in the publisher remain untouched? If so, will the rows from the publisher replicate back to the subscriber but now with the same rowguid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same logical row has two different `rowguid` values at publisher and subscriber, then you're having a conflict.

Changes are replicated using the `rowguid` column, so different `rowguid` means different rows as far as replication is concerned. You can safely delete the duplicate row at the subscriber and the changes won't be replicated to the publisher (the row with a matching `rowguid` is not present at the publisher due to the upload conflict).

Once the row is deleted at the subscriber, the merge agent will be able to insert at the subscriber the row from the publisher.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand that with MERGE replication it doesn't matter if you delete from the publisher or subscriber but I deleted from the subscriber.  After I deleted, the next time replication ran, the publisher pushed over the rows back into the subscriber database but with the same rowguid this time.  0 conflicts now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Merge Replication is bi-directional by default so if you delete a row at the Subscriber, that change will replicate and the same row will be deleted at the Publisher, and vice versa.

Comment: Is this true even though they have different rowguid?

Comment: Merge Replication uses the rowguid column to uniquely identify every row in every published table.  If you delete a row on the Subscriber with a specific rowguid, that same row with that rowguid will be deleted on the Publisher.  Make sense?

Comment: Thank you for your help Brandon.  I understand what you're saying. In my case my rows had different rowguid which was causing conflicts.